# Flutter sqflite error SqfliteDatabaseException

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have a flutter application with a sqflite database, when i save a new record it saves normal but when i change and save it breaks and shows this error:

[image]

```
await db.execute("
      CREATE TABLE $registroTable(
      $idColumn INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      $viagemColumn INTEGER,
      $categoriaColumn INTEGER,
      $dateColumn DATE,
      $tituloColumn TEXT,
      $valorColumn FLOAT,
      FOREIGN KEY ($viagemColumn) REFERENCES $viagemTable($idColumn),
      FOREIGN KEY ($categoriaColumn) REFERENCES $categoriaTable($idColumn)
      );");
    });
```

The exception has occurred:

> ```
> SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase
> Code=19 "UNIQUE constraint failed: registroTable.idColumn"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=UNIQUE constraint failed:
> registroTable.idColumn}) sql 'INSERT INTO registroTable (viagemColumn,
> categoriaColumn, dateColumn, tituloColumn, valorColumn, idColumn)
> VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' args [1, 1, 2019-10-27, milho, 15000.0,
> 1]})
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it looks like you are inserting (which tries to add a new row) to the table.  I believe a row with the same id already exists so the database stops you from adding another with the same id (I believe id is unique).

You should instead be using "update" function from sqflite API when you want to change the values.

Comment: Yes, you're right, now I realize that my question was kind of stupid. Just add a test for the update!

Comment: Glad it worked. If you like, you can accept my response as an answer.